# Scoping a Transform in Cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I'm working with a very large set of already existing cucumber features, and adding additional tests. For those new tests I'm also trying to use transforms to simplify repetitive tasks.

How can I add a transform without breaking already existing tests? I've already added context to the capture group, but since the context is from the same business domain as the pre-existing tests it can easily end up matching.

Is there a way to only apply a transform to certain steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a tag and a Before filter to set an instance variable in the World.  This is then available to your Transform so that it can perform tag-specific transforms.  For example, if you only wanted to Transform integers when the @hook tag is present:

```
Transform /(\d+)/ do |num|
  if @hook
    num.to_i
  else
    num
  end
end

Before('@hook') do
  @hook = true
end
```

A new World is created for each Scenario and the Before filters are called.  So @hook will be reset for each Scenario.

Comment: Interesting idea, but now feature files would have to be aware of transformations, when it is really the step definition that cares

Comment: @Chris Yes I suppose I didn't answer your *real* question about applying the transform to just certain steps.  You did say that they're additional tests, so I thought they were new Scenarios.

Comment: Thanks, this might be the best that is possible at the moment!